# finding the index of the elements appended to new list from its old list - python 2

Tags: python, list

I have two lists (A and B) with some common elements in between them. I want to create a new list (C) with all the common elements from A that are also in B, as well have the index of where the elements was originally in A.

The two lists are as fallows,

```
A=[[[a, b], [c, d]],
   [[e, f], [f, t]],
   [[a, b], [c, d]],
   [[g, h], [t, r]]]
B=[[[a, b], [c, d]],
   [[g, h], [t, r]]]
```

The code Im using to find the common elements are as fallows,

```
C=[[ ]]
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] in B:
        C[0].append(A[i])
```

The output is perfect, except I'd like to add in the index of the elements in C from where there come from in A (even if there are duplicates), possible besides each elements or even in a new list, although Im not sure the code that would do that, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have `C` as a one-element list containing a sub-list, rather than just initialise it with `C=[]` and then do `C.append(...)` where you currently have `C[0].append(...)`?

Comment: I left it like that cause I actually had more then the A, B lists. The common elements from those 2 would go into C[0], but for the rest of my lists, Id add them into other C[ ], etc. But they weren't important to add, actually even the C[0] isn't really necessary, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this  line of code:

```
C[0].append(A[i])
```

with:

```
C[0].append([A[i], i])
```

which forms `C` with each element in the format `[element, index]`.

Comment: Arguably it may be more pythonic to use 2-element tuples instead of 2-element lists here - `(A[i], i)` in place of `[A[i], i]` - although they are of course being appended to a list.